# Components and Sub components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-loader

I'm new to Vue.js and I'm having a bit of trouble using components with sub-components. I have the following `.vue` files

**app.vue**

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <menu></menu>
    <h1>Create Your MIA</h1>
    <div id="board"></div>
    <slider>
      <skin></skin>
    </slider>
  </section>
</template>
```

**slider.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="slider-panel">
    <h3>{{* heading}}</h3>
    <div class="slider">
      <slot>
        Some content
      </slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import skin from "./skin";
  export default {
    components: {
      skin: skin
    }
  };
</script>
```

**skin.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div v-for="colour in colours">
      <div :style="{ backgroundColor: colour }">
        <img src="../assets/images/MIA.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        heading: "Choose Skin Tone"
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

I'm trying to load the skin sub component into the component. Everything works well except for the skin sub component as it doesn't get compiled.  I do not get any compile or vue related errors though. I also wanted to be able to have several instances of the slider component like this

**app.vue**

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <menu></menu>
    <h1>Create Your MIA</h1>
    <div id="board"></div>
    <slider>
      <skin></skin>
    </slider>
    <slider>
      <foo></foo>
    </slider>
    <slider>
      <bar></bar>
    </slider>
  </section>
</template>
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36761185/931742) which refers to a `is=` attribute that will transclude the sub-component template

so in app.vue

```
<slider-component>
      <div is="skin-component" v-for="colour in colours"></div>
    </slider-component>
```

and then add child components

Comment: That's actually a good idea. Let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: it did @HectorLorenzo

Answer (score 9):

I'm not 100% sure of what you want to achieve here, but to compile a component inside a component, you need to add the child component inside the parent's template, like this:

Slider.vue (I've simplified the structure):

```
<template>
  <div id="slider-panel">
    <h3>{{* heading}}</h3>
    <skin></skin>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import skin from './skin'
export default {
  components : {
    'skin': skin
  }
}
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <menu></menu>
    <h1>Create Your MIA</h1>
    <div id="board"></div>
    <slider></slider>
  </section>
</template>
```

Actually, if you add `skin` in the app's template inside of adding it in the `slider` component template, it gets included (and rendered) assuming that its scope is `app`, not `slider`. In order to add `skin` inside `slider` scope, it needs to be added to `slider`'s template. Check this: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope

Some other things:

- Use a hyphen-separated name for the components, with at least 2 words: `<custom-slider>` instead of `<slider>`, for example, following the Web Components API (otherwise it might collide with current or upcoming web components).
- Slots are complicated to grasp, so read this carefully: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots

Good luck!

**Update:**

If you want the `slider` component to be content agnostic and be able to insert anything you want inside it, you have two options (that I can think of):

1. Remove all the logic from the `slider` component and make `skin` a descendant from `app`. Then use slots in the `slider` component, as follows:

Slider.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="slider-panel">
    <h3>{{* heading}}</h3>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <menu></menu>
    <h1>Create Your MIA</h1>
    <div id="board"></div>
    <slider>
      <skin></skin>
    </slider>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import skin from './skin'
export default {
  skin: skin
}
</script>
```

2. If you know that the slider will always have a closed set of components inside, you can use dynamic components: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I separated the `skin` component and the `slider` component because I wanted to be able to "reuse" the slider components and swap out the `skin` for some something else e.g. `<slider><foo></foo></slider>` Would I be able to complies this without duplicating the slider-component?

Comment: Why did you say a "descendant" of "app.vue" and not a "child component"?

Comment: No reason, but you are right, "child component" makes more sense.

Comment: Hmm... I'm looking over the code and I don't think it will work as I want to run multiple *slider-components* in the **app.vue** component

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1 for the `... hyphen-separated name for the components` suggestion.