# Using Laravel includes inside a vue component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I have a set of components, some components include other components via `@include('my-sub-component')`

The issue is that when I want to use vue I have to put the entire component in the vue.js file inside the template tags.

But inside the template I want to use the `@include` so I can include some sub components. This does not work.

How can I include blade components inside a vue component?

Comment: Share your code. There's no way to figure out why isn't working without code. =)

Comment: There is no code, I've explained the issue. You should not need code to answer this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861672/components-and-sub-components - does this help at all? I know you say you're using @include but this may be a different way of achieving it

Comment: Thanks Andy but not quite what i am after.

Comment: You should have more detailed question, the "component" is Laravel Blade Component or Vue Component.

Comment: I doubt you can do that because blade gets processed before Vue. Instead you should create all your components in `.vue` files if you want to include them in your Vue templates, and then either get the data from a backend api or pass it to the components through props or using a Vuex store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible. You can't use PHP (Laravel Blade) `.blade.php` tags inside Vue Component `.js`, of course Vue can't execute PHP script in this case. The possible use case is you use the Vue Component inside Laravel Blade.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you can get to this is to use [inline templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates). You can't access blade directives it if you are writing your templates in single file components and compiling them with webpack or something because they are not being rendered with PHP.

You could put the style and scripts components in the SFC though and but in order to use blade directives the template would need to be in a `.blade.php` file

Comment: Sure? `@include` is a blade tag, are you sure Vue can do this? Of course, ithe question is laravel specific use case.

Comment: Yes, I've done it before. You might need to escape the VueJS tags because they sorta conflict with the Blade ones. It works because the templates are generated in PHP and not served as a static JS asset.

Comment: You should see his explanation `How can I include blade components inside a vue component?` and he wants to use `@include` inside Vue Component (.js) file. Your answer is correct, but It's not answering his question.